# how to prevent grid image from getting too big if using 1fr with minmax()

Tags: css, css-grid, minmax

This CSS almost does what is needed:

- always fill the container 100% so no margin is seen.
- resize images to fill the container without media queries or calculations.

but certain screen sizes create a larger image than is wanted

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 6px;
}
```

the 1fr does great EXCEPT for when the images get too big.
If I use minmax(200px, 300px), then most of the time, the margins get too big.

Is there a way to get the benefits of 1fr, but also have a max-width as well?
so resizing the images SMALLER is okay, but increasing the image size is not okay.

Comment: Max-with can be used on the grid cell element itself or img probably in your case.

Comment: Can you add your code in order to see this?

Comment: Hi A. Meshu, https://codepen.io/trynn/pen/jOELKam
Looking for zero margins and on mobile screens to have 3 images on a row,